# Make a object follow another object to scale

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm making a vr game and want a 3d minimap. I have a script for a object to follow another object with distance with a 1 to 1 scale.

What i want is that if my player moved +1 on the x axes than my capsule moves 0,1.
So something like the `player position x 0,1 = capsule position`.
I want my Y posision to be always the same.
I'm pretty new to this so i'm using a lot of help from google.

This is the code that i have now:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class minimapplayer : MonoBehaviour
{    public Transform leader;
    public float followSharpness = 0.1f;

    Vector3 _followOffset;

    void Start()
    {
        // Cache the initial offset at time of load/spawn:
        _followOffset = transform.position - leader.position;
    }

    void LateUpdate () 
    {
        // Apply that offset to get a target position.
        Vector3 targetPosition = leader.position + _followOffset;

        // Keep our y position unchanged.
        targetPosition.y = transform.position.y;

        // Smooth follow.    
        transform.position += (targetPosition - transform.position) * followSharpness;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can constantly store the last player position,
and then move the object based on the difference between the old and new position, scaled

```cs
public class FollowObj : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    private float followScale;

    // Yoor follow reference, assign it
    private Player playerRef;

    private Vector2 lastPlayerPos;

    private void Start(){
        lastPlayerPos = playerRef.transform.position;
    }

    private void Update(){
        Vector2 newPlayerPos = playerRef.transform.position;

        // Get a heading that points to the new position
        Vector2 playerTravelVector = newPlayerPos - lastPlayerPos;

        transform.position += playerTravelVector * followScale;

        lastPlayerPos = newPlayerPos;
    }
}
```